# How can I make a motion counter with OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python

I have made a motion detector with OpenCV and now I want to add a function that sends a notification to my phone when someone is in picture. The problem is when I detect if someone is in picture, the notifictaion sends every time I move. So I want the motion detector to send ONE notification every time someone goes into picture. Like a security camera.

I have done some research and I think I need a motion counter that counts every time someone goes into picture. And then the detector sends a notification every time the motion counter increases by 1. How can I do this code and add it to my detector code?

Here's my code (the notification is print("Hello"), just for now)

```
import cv2
import winsound

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while cam.isOpened():
    ret, frame1 = cam.read()
    ret, frame2 = cam.read()
    diff = cv2.absdiff(frame1, frame2)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=3)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # cv2.drawContours(frame1, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    motion = "No motion detected..."

    for c in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < 700:
            continue
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(frame1, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        winsound.Beep(500, 100)   
        motion = "Motion detected!"

    if motion == "Motion detected!":
        print("Hello")

    if cv2.waitKey(10) == ord("q"):
        break
    cv2.imshow("Cam", frame1)
```